# How can I make a taskbar in either HTML or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web, taskbar

I'm currently making an online OS and I want a taskbar of course.
A taskbar that works somewhat like Windows taskbar at the bottom of the screen, like it has some applications there and when you open an application it appears on the taskbar, and when you minimize it minimizes to the taskbar, and when you click the minimized application on the taskbar it appears back up again as it was before.

I've searched everywhere on the internet and it seems like I can't find any information about this.
How can I make a taskbar that works like Windows taskbar?

Any information and any link is highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: There isn't some magical `<taskbar>` tag that you're going to find.  Stick some divs down there, style them appropriately, and add your content.  I would use links to on-page anchors for switching applications.

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is using YII's menu, and hacking it as you wish.

Comment: Are you really asking how you can anchor some content to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Although embarking on a quest can certainly be a lot of fun - many people have made "online OS's/Desktops" and yet I've personally seen none of them succeed.  If you aren't doing this for kicks... you should be aware that there is *likely* no business plan that you can apply to this and achieve meaningful ROI. e.g. I can't recall whose quote it is but it applies here: "Just because you **can** do it in JavaScript... doesn't mean you should do it."

Comment: @scunliffe Au contraire. I worked on a proprietary application that is currently used to administer several hundred client sites for my previous employer. I think their bottom line is in direct contravention to your assertion. The jewel in the crown is a browser-based windowing system. The clients all love it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html) has a nice looking (over used) [Navbar](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar).

This might not be what you're looking for, or it might be overkill for what you're looking for, but in a lot of cases Bootstrap is a great launching pad for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is definitely the way to go. I worked on an application that did just this... But I think this is what you need: [jQuery Taskbar Plugin](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138086/Taskbar) to make your life simpler.